# Gain Access to Mouse Clicks in C# Component

Tags: c#, events, scintilla

I am using the ScintillaNET component and I am attempting to capture clicks in the margin, as this will determine how I respond.  Unfortunately, the margins capture the mouse events (and don't provide a way, from what I can see, to get the click information - number of clicks, mouse button clicked, etc).

If this is indeed the case (I am not able to get that info directly), what is another way of capturing what the mouse is doing *before* the MarginClick event is fired?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not figure out a solution to my specific question.  Instead, I changed my code to look at the modifier keys that are pressed when the MarginClick event is fired.  This solution works well, and I am going to accept this answer.  However, if someone can specifically answer my question, I will accept that answer.